# Calculating percent difference from average value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd like to get a price level percentage (lower or higher than average product price) by store but I really don't know where to start. How can I calculate this?

I've got a MySQL table with data like this:

```
product_id | store_id | price | amount
1          | 1        | 10.00 | 1 
1          | 2        | 12.00 | 1 
1          | 3        | 8.00  | 1
2          | 1        | 21.20 | 1 
2          | 3        | 29.50 | 1
2          | 3        | 40.00 | 2
```

I'd like to calculate it per store with all the products but to make this example easier I use only the product with id 1. I think:

10 is the average price of product 1, because it's between 8 and 12. So 10 equals 0% for store 1. To calculate the price level for store 3 I can do this: 100 - (8 * 100 / 10) = 20%. But how can I do this with multiple products? And not every store does have all the products and eventually I'd like to fit it in one MySQL query if possible with a result like:

```
store_id  |  percentage
1         |  0
2         |  -20
3         |  20
```

Comment: Can a store have a product more than once?

Comment: @McAdam331 That is fantastically unlikely. Let's assume not!

Comment: @McAdam331 yes, that's possible. I've changed the example table, forgot this point. Thanks!

Comment: @Roy on second thought, that still may not change the query, because you want average price per item. If you need to know the average price of that item at each store, you'll need to write a subquery for it. Also, taking your comment into consideration I have edited my answer, I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke this down into multiple pieces and then put them back together.

First, I got the average price for each product_id:

```
SELECT product_id, AVG(price) AS averagePrice
FROM myTable
GROUP BY product_id;
```

The following makes the assumption that a product_id cannot appear at a store more than once. So I've joined the tables together, so I can see what the store charges next to the average price for that item:

```
SELECT m.product_id, m.store_id, m.price, t.averagePrice
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT product_id, AVG(price) AS averagePrice
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY product_id) t ON t.product_id = m.product_id;
```

Once I had that, I was able to take the difference between averagePrice and price, divide by average price and multiply by 100 like this:

```
SELECT m.product_id, m.store_id, (100 * ((m.price - t.averagePrice) / t.averagePrice)) AS difference
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT product_id, AVG(price) AS averagePrice
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY product_id) t ON t.product_id = m.product_id;
```

It worked for me in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df952/6).

**EDIT**

To get the average price difference per store (for all items) I believe you can just take the above, and by averaging the stores price difference on each individual item, you'll get the average price difference for that store, like this:

```
SELECT store_id, AVG(difference) AS averagePriceDifference
FROM(
  SELECT m.product_id, m.store_id, (100 * ((m.price - t.averagePrice) / t.averagePrice)) AS difference
  FROM myTable m
  JOIN(
    SELECT product_id, AVG(price) AS averagePrice
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY product_id) t ON t.product_id = m.product_id) t
GROUP BY store_id;
```

Here it is in [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df952/11).

**EDIT 2**

Again, I will rework this in pieces and try and put it back together. I know I will need a subquery to get the number of stores (so I know if a product is sold at each store) and I can use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct store_id) AS storecount
FROM myTable;
```

Now, I can use that as a subquery to get products sold at every store. I can group by product_id and amount, so that if every store has the item at amount 1, and every store has item at amount 2, it will show up each time.

```
SELECT product_id, amount
FROM myTable
GROUP BY product_id, amount
HAVING COUNT(distinct store_id) = (SELECT COUNT(distinct store_id) FROM myTable);
```

I can add to the above to get the average price of each item for that amount:

```
SELECT product_id, amount, AVG(price) AS averagePriceForAmount
FROM myTable
GROUP BY product_id, amount
HAVING COUNT(distinct store_id) = (SELECT COUNT(distinct store_id) FROM myTable);
```

Once I have that, I can calculate the average price difference for each store using the same method I used earlier, like this:

```
SELECT m.store_id, m.product_id, m.amount, (100 * ((m.price - t.averagePriceForAmount) / t.averagePriceForAmount)) AS differenceForItemAndAmount
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT product_id, amount, AVG(price) AS averagePriceForAmount
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY product_id, amount) t ON t.product_id = m.product_id AND t.amount = m.amount
GROUP BY m.store_id;
```

[This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7f2a1/7) will return the store, product_id, the amount of the product, and the store's difference from the average price for that product for that amount. If you want the average price difference for the store on all items, try this:

```
SELECT store_id, AVG(differenceForItemAndAmount) AS averageDifferenceForStore
FROM(
  SELECT m.store_id, m.product_id, m.amount, (100 * ((m.price - t.averagePriceForAmount) / t.averagePriceForAmount)) AS differenceForItemAndAmount
  FROM myTable m
  JOIN(
    SELECT product_id, amount, AVG(price) AS averagePriceForAmount
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY product_id, amount) t ON t.product_id = m.product_id AND t.amount = m.amount
  GROUP BY m.store_id) t
GROUP BY store_id;
```

Again, this will only include items sold at every store, that has the same amount discount at every store.

Comment: I just copy in the comment I've posted on Multisync answer because this does the same: I'd like to get a percentage per store for all products, not per product as your query does. But thanks for helping!

Comment: I will try to adjust it when I have time today, if this is still an open issue for you.

Comment: Also, @Roy wouldn't your expected results change then?

Comment: Thanks for your edited answer, but this one doesn't do anything with the `amount` column. So the percentage can be too low (not that cheap) when a store sells multiple products at once (quantity discount). I think we have to see products who have a amount more than one as different products in the query. What do you think?

Comment: @Roy are you saying the one in the last row should be treated as a price of $20? 40.00/2?

Comment: That's possible too but I think that's not fair for other stores who don't give quantity discount. I think that it should be compared with products from other stores who are selling the same product with the same amount. If other stores doesn't sell the product with the same amount it shouldn't be used for the percentage. A `group by` with `product_id` and `amount` I think?

Comment: @Roy it's getting kind of difficult to picture. Can you re-work your expected results table?

Comment: I still want to get the same result as in my question. You're query is good but it compares a products with different amounts as the same. So the percentage of store 3 will be to low because the last product in my example (product 2, store 3) is compared with product 2 from store 1 and the price it higher because you'll get 2 of them.

Comment: @Roy so don't consider product 2 because it's not sold at every store?

Comment: @Roy my question is getting a bit longer, but I hope this new edit is a little better. I still get your expected results even though I've updated the original table.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I hope we can get to the solution! I've created a SQL Fiddle with (I hope) a better explanation of possibilities and examples: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2554/1. As written there in the comments It's hard for me too validate the results of your queries because I can't recalculate it when I add more products.

Comment: After some tests your last query was the one I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Write a query to get the average price per product:

```
select product_id, avg(price) as average_price
from mysqltable
group by product_id
```

Use it as a subquery and refer to avg price from it (using your calc for the deviation of average price)

```
select product_id, store_id, 100 - (price * 100 / average_price)
from mysqltable a
inner join     (select product_id, avg(price) as average_price
                from mysqltable
                group by product_id) b
on a.product_id = b.product_id
```

Comment: I just copy in the comment I've posted on Multisync answer because this does the same: I'd like to get a percentage per store for all products, not per product as your query does. But thanks for helping!

Comment: @roy we can addres that...is each product weighted as one for the purposes of averaging?

Comment: see my comments on McAdam331 his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.product_id, t1.store_id, 
       100 - (t1.price * 100 / t2.avg_price)
from tab t1 join (select product_id, avg(price) as avg_price 
                  from tab group by product_id) t2
            on t1.product_id = t2.product_id;
```

Calculate avg for each product in a subquery then join with the table to produce the results you need.

Comment: I'd like to get a percentage per store for all products, not per product as your query does. But thanks for helping!